# "A quarter of us is going to lose our jobs" or "A quarter of us is going to lose his job"

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, possessive-determiners

During my English lesson, I found this sentence in the book

> *A quarter of us is going to lose our job.*

I think it's wrong but the teachers disagree with me. I think that the subject is "a quarter",
so it should be:

> A quarter of us is going to lose **his** job
>   or
>   A quarter of us is going to lose **their** job**s**

Comment: *A quarter of us* includes the speaker. It's like I am speaking in our group that some of us are going to lose our job.

Comment: if it was "you" insted of us, you should write "a quarter of you is going to lose his job" or "a quarter of you is going to lose your job".


it sounds really strange to me that the pronom doesnt relate to the subject

Comment: Actually, if it's you-plural, it should be, per my answer below, "a quarter of you will lose (are going to lose) your jobs".

Comment: Yes. When I say *A quarter of you*, it doesn't include me the speaker. Then I would say: *A quarter of you are going to lose* **your** job.

Comment: You're both wrong, but for different reasons. See my answer below. Your teacher is wrong because it's not one job shared among a quarter of us; you're wrong because the subject and verb don't agree in number.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the sort of question I'd expect to see on [ell.se] rather than here; I'm not VTCing, however.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I don't think the question is so cut and dried as you seem to make it out to be. See [my question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/they-write-in-their-school-diary-or-diaries) posted on ELL.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - There's plenty of ambiguity in that question, because the class as a whole could be collaboratively writing in a single diary belonging to the entire class (or school). If each child is independently writing in a separately-owned diary, I'd write "The children are writing in their diaries", but even that can be construed ambiguously; do any of the children maintain more than one diary?

Comment: Here, though, there isn't one job shared by a quarter of us. We have jobs, we don't have a job. Thus, one of us can lose his job, but a quarter of us can't lose our job, because it's not a single job, it's the collection of jobs that the affected people - a quarter of us - have and are about to lose. Thus, a quarter of us are going to lose our jobs.

Comment: primax79 could you please cite the name of the textbook? Out of curiosity, I tried "googling" the original sentence and the only results that appeared were your question. Changing the verb "is" to "are"  and   "job" to "jobs" ["A quarter of us are going to lose our jobs"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=Qbn_WqzjGoHQkwXu9pvYAg&q=%22A+quarter+of+us+are+going+to+lose+our+jobs%22&oq=%22A+quarter+of+us+are+going+to+lose+our+jobs%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...10973.10973.0.12354.1.1.0.0.0.0.109.109.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.i_xNCl2-r4o) also made no difference to the results.

Comment: Curiously, Google only produces 4 results for ["a quarter of us are going to"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=L7r_Wt2SDIGWkwWtx56YCw&q=%22A+quarter+of+us+are+going+to%22&oq=%22A+quarter+of+us+are+going+to%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20421.27412.0.28545.16.16.0.0.0.0.149.2099.0j16.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.852...0i8i7i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i7i10i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.7h8mHsEz_sk) *but* ["a quarter of us will"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22A+quarter+of+us+will%22&num=20&ei=9Lr_WsvjN4zksAezhpfQCw&start=100&sa=N&biw=1316&bih=619) produces about 104 instances.

Answer (score 3):

Since you’re talking about [some of] *us* (first person plural), your subject and verb must agree in person and number, and if the object maps one-to-one with the subject (e.g., each person has one job, not one job shared among multiple people), it should also agree in number - thus, I’d say *our jobs*: *A quarter of us will lose our jobs.* If you need/want the “going”, *A quarter of us **are going** to lose our jobs.*

It has been argued that “A quarter...” makes it a singular subject; I (and those that share my linguistic environment) disagree: The basic subject is plural, *us*. If we start from that, we get *We (All of us) are going to lose our jobs.* But it's not all of us: ***Some of us** are going to lose our jobs.* The subject is still plural. Changing *some* to a specific amount - *a quarter* - doesn’t change the number of the subject; it's still plural, *A quarter of us*, thus: *A quarter of us are going to lose our jobs.*

If the subject were to change to *One of us*, then the verb *would* become singular - *One of us is going to lose his/her/xir job.*

Comment: **A** quarter [of us] *is*

Comment: I prefer "A quarter of us are..."   Maybe this is a UK/US difference?  (Jeff & I US against Mari-Lou UK.) I did find Ngram showing "quarter of them are" far ahead of "quarter of them is".

Comment: To me, and to everyone I've asked here in the NYC area, it's not "A quarter [of us] is...", it's "[A quarter of] {We -> us} are...", i.e., "We are going to lose our jobs" -> "Some of us are going to lose our jobs" -> "A quarter of us are going to lose our jobs"

Comment: I won't rule out the possibility that this is a BrE/AmE difference, but I really suspect not; the issue seems to be a misinterpretation of number. See my transitional argument in the comment above.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+few+of+us+is%2C+a+few+of+us+are&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20of%20us%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20of%20us%20are%3B%2Cc0) 'a few of us is/a few of us are' shows massive use of 'are' (since it is juxtaposed to the plural 'us').

Comment: @Mari-LouA if there are exactly 4 people, I would be willing to let "a quarter of us is" slide, but otherwise it sounds like bad grammar to me.

Comment: (Although I would also accept it for a situation like "a quarter of us is three people total.")

Comment: *A quarter of us are* sounds more natural to me, too (I'm Canadian if that's relevant), mainly because I put the emphasis on *us* as the main subject of the sentence, even though it is being modified by *quarter of*. However, I would use *a quarter of us* ***is*** *not a large enough number* (assuming I used that awkward phrasing) because the subject shifts from *us* to the number  itself. . .

Comment: @Hellion "a quarter of anything" is equivalent to 25%. Would you say "In {city} 25% of the population is (or) are unemployed?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - _Population_ is an odd word, in this case - grammatically, it appears singular in number, but whether it takes a plural form in the verb really depends on context. For your example, _25% of the population **are** unemployed_, but _25% of the population **is** 32,768_.